# ckWebServicePlugin gives empty result

Tags: php, web-services, soap, symfony1

I'm facing an issue with an complex array, the response only says:

```xml
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.pharmadvisor.com/ws/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:FichasRepresentanteResponse>
            <result/>
        </ns1:FichasRepresentanteResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But I've already declared WSMethod:

```php
/**
 * Recupera las fichas del representante
 *
 * @WSMethod(name="FichasRepresentante", webservice="webservices")
 *
 * @param string $bd_nombre Nombre de la Base de Datos
 * @param string $id_usuario Id del representante
 * @return wsFicha[]
 */

public function executeFichas_representante($request){

    $arrFichas = array();

    ...

    $fichaMed = new wsFicha();
    $fichaMed->id_formato = 1;
    $fichaMed->nombre = "Médicos";
    $fichaMed->abreviatura = "Med";
    $fichaMed->gps_maestro_contacto = 2;
    $arrFichas[1] = $fichaMed;

    ...

    $this->result = $arrFichas;
}
```

And wsFicha is

```php
class wsFicha {

    /**
     * Id formato de la Ficha
     * @var integer
     */

    public $id_formato;

    /**
     * Nombre de la ficha
     * @var string
     */

    public $nombre;

    /**
     * Abreviatura
     * @var string
     */

    public $abreviatura;

    /**
     * Si la posición GPS depende de la base (1) o del contacto (2)
     * @var integer
     */

    public $gps_maestro_contacto;

}
```

Finally, `app.yml` stands

```
  classmap:
    wsFicha: wsFicha
    wsFichaArray: ckGenericArray
```

What could i'been doing wrong so the webservice doesnt generate my data, also to note that if i put `return sfView::ERROR` only for testing, don't works and gets ignored.

Comment: I only have similar empty response when I cannot access the action in question, i.e. can you check HTTP headers? If it's not a 401 unauthorized

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I gave up on this by means of short time I had. So now i'm using Symfony2, and it's more simple.